# Eloquent functionaliy lost in Else{}

Tags: php, laravel

i have a route with the following:

simply put i have the following:

```
Route::get('login/linkedin', function()
{

               $userid = Auth::id();
               dd($userid);   <----THIS WORKS   

    $provider = new Linkedin(Config::get('social.linkedin'));

    if ( !Input::has('code')) {
        // If we don't have an authorization code, get one
        $provider->authorize(); 

    }else{

}
```

but when i do this :

```
Route::get('login/linkedin', function()
{



    $provider = new Linkedin(Config::get('social.linkedin'));

    if ( !Input::has('code')) {
        // If we don't have an authorization code, get one
        $provider->authorize(); 

    }else{

              $userid = Auth::id();
               dd($userid);   <----THIS Returns NULL  

}
```

Why cant i use the Auth:: after the else?

Comment: I'd test if `$provider = new Linkedin(Config::get('social.linkedin'));` does something to the currently logged-in user by `dd()`ing `Auth::id()` before and after that line.

Comment: Missing the `}` in your else?

Answer (score -1):

Why not try something like this:

```
Route::get('login/linkedin', function()
{

    $userid_aux = Auth::id();

    $provider = new Linkedin(Config::get('social.linkedin'));

    if ( !Input::has('code')) {
        // If we don't have an authorization code, get one
        $provider->authorize(); 

    }else{

        dd($userid_aux);   <----THIS Returns NULL
    }

}
```

Maybe something is overwriting you variable, try with another variable name.

Sorry for the vague answer years ago.

Comment: Maybe explain a litter more? if you are going to **answer a question** then **elaborate**.

Comment: It'd be better to figure out *why* it's happening than make a hacky workaround.

Comment: The problem seem to rest inside the line : $provider->authorize(); before that line everything works fine. after that line everything is messed up.

Comment: @Vudew Unlikely - if the `else` is happening, `authorize()` is never being called.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing this can be one of two things:

1) The user session have expired and no longer signed in, or

2) You are missing the closing `});`  (Unless you forgot to copy and paste it into your question.)

Comment: 1 is unlikely given the problem description, and 2 would give a parse error instead of `dd()` output.

Comment: I think it lost the session. the line : provieder->uathorize() seems to be the culprit

Comment: @Vudew Unlikely - if the `else` is happening, `authorize()` is never being called.